# MIP threaded pipe in NPSM female threads

Tags: plumbing, plumbing-fixture, pex, threading, npt

I'm installing a freestanding tub faucet. According to the manufacturer's spec sheet the supply lines have 1/2 inch female NPSM threads, which I believe is a straight thread. I'm trying to attach these to 1/2 inch PEX-B. All of the male thread PEX fittings that I can find have MIP or MNPT threads, which I believe is a tapered thread.

Will the male MIP or MNPT be able to screw securely into a female NPSM? If not, then where would I find a fitting that would allow me to make this connection? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Have the fittings got a gasket/washer in them?

Comment: @Ecnerwal Yes, there appears to be a gasket in them. I've added a photo. Thank you :)

Comment: Those look like self sealing fittings without the proper mate they may not allow any flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the gasket required to make the seal, this marriage of star-crossed lovers should work out fine.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it worked perfectly with the 1/2 inch MIP fitting.